# In Intellij, how can I throw an exception at a break point?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I see lots of questions about how to make Intellij break on exceptions.  I'm trying to do something different: I want to throw an exception at a breakpoint so that I can see what will happen if an exception were to occur at that code.

I've figured out ways to force this.  For example, if I have a variable called `willBeUsed`, I can hit a breakpoint and add a watch that says `willBeUsed = null`.  This will trigger a NullPointerException *eventually*.

But I'm in a situation where I want to throw an `IOException` to see what happens.  There's no way to trick my code into doing that.  When I add a watch that says `throw new IOException()` it gives me an error saying, "unexpected tokens".

As a work around, I can modify the code to throw the exception and redeploy.  But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in the debugger without modifying source code.

Comment: It's unlikely that there's a way to do what you're asking.  I would suggest looking into a different design that more readily facilitates this kind of testing - for example [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: @RobI Dependency injection is good.  I don't see how it helps me here.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Short idea: make an interface to do what you're doing in the block of code that sometimes raises an exception (say, `IODoer` with `do()` method).  Your real implementation is in one concrete class `IODoerImpl`, with all the real code, but you have another concrete class `TestIODoer`, which raises an exception every time you call its `do()` method, or every other time, or whenever... Normally your program uses the real implementation, but during testing you can inject this test class instead.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can right-click on stacktrace and choose 'Throw Exception'

[image]

(Since 2018.1 version. See JetBrains issue: [IDEA-148408](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148408))

Comment: How to do it ? Please add some screen shots.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin You can right-click on stacktrace and choose 'Throw Exception'. There is attached screenshot at mbaranauskas's answer.

Comment: This option is also available in the menu under Run -> Throw Exception, which can be clicked while debugging.

Comment: **For me this ended in hours of bug searching today, but there is a solution.**

**Bug description:** Using a swing java application, when I threw the exception this way, it was triggered correctly (I traced it) for the first time but the application did not behave correct afterwards: I could not start new IProgressWorker jobs.

**Solution:** The method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094415/3895476 works.

Answer (score 8):

How about placing the `throw` statement in an `if` block, and only change the condition, e.g.:

```
boolean shouldThrowException = false;
// ....
if ( shouldThrowException ) //place breakpoint here
{
    throw new IOException();
}
```

When you hit the breakpoint, change the value of `shouldThrowException` to true.

Comment: I pretty much already gave this as a workaround in my question.  But if it's the only way, I guess it's the only way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have missed it in your question, sorry for not being too helpful..

Answer (score 8):

In the 'Debbuger' window 'Frames' section right-click current function and select 'Throw Exception'. Then enter exception you want to throw.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how this can be done. I've tried two approaches (perhaps my ideas will lead to some other ideas

1) I tried to use the debuggers "log evaluated expression" to `throw new IOException()` but all I get is a message that IDEA couldn't evaluate the expression.

2) I also tried to set a break point and when it stopped I open up the "evaluate expression" dialog to throw a new exception but that didn't work either.

I don't think the debugger can throw exceptions.
@Binyamin's solution will work but you already mentioned that in your question. I can only add that in IDEA it's possible to uncheck the "suspend" checkbox and enter `shouldThrowException = true` in the "log evaluated expression" box. This will cause the debugger to just change the value (and log it) but not stop which is great in code that have many concurrent threads.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have tried this but you could perhaps create a static method that only throws `IOException` and then call that method by issuing `Evaluate Expression`.

Simple example code:

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        doStuff();
    }

    private static void throwException() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }

    private static void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("doStuff");
    }
}
```

Set a breakpoint on the `System.out.println` line:

[image]

Bring up the `Evaluate Expression...` window and call the `throwException` method (evaluate) and then you'll get a stack trace from within `doStuff`:

[image]

The exception will of course be in `throwException` but you see the whole call stack as well.

Comment: Yep, that'd work.  But I'd still have to redeploy.  But, what would be neat is to put this in a library and then I could call it whenever I need on any project.  This way I wouldn't need to modify any source files in the main project or redeploy.  I can use a maven scope so it doesn't get deployed when I package.

Comment: @tieTYT Yes that was exactly my thought.

Comment: I tried this out and the output of the console doesn't show an exception in it.  I think that it evaluates the exception in its own instance so it doesn't affect the main thread.

Comment: @tieTYT The problem with IOException is that it is a checked exception and therefor all methods must declare a throws IOException. And if you want to suddenly throw IOException from the debugger in a method that **doesn't** have it declared, what would happen?

Comment: Although that's a good point, 1) if my source code does happen to throw IOException that problem still exists 2) if my `throwException` method throws a RuntimeException, my issue still occurs as described in my comment.  So this isn't a way to test what will happen if an exception is thrown at a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way where you take advantage of the JVM HotSwapping.

Let's assume that you are deploying code to some server. Then when you start the application make sure that you turn on remote debugging (which I think you have since you are debugging and are talking about deployment). If not then it will work evenly fine in the local debugger.

Now I have two classes, Main and Other.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        doStuff();
    }

    private static void doStuff() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("doStuff");
        Other.otherStuff();
    }

    public static void throwException() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Other {
    public static void otherStuff() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("Some_File.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

The `throwException()` could be placed anywhere as long as it is "globally" available, in some util class for example. Now it is just placed in my Main class for convenience.

Now we can have a breakpoint set in our `doStuff()` method and while being held there we can change the code in the `otherStuff()` method so that it calls our static `throwException()` method.

```
public static void otherStuff() throws IOException {
    Main.throwException();
    File file = new File("Some_File.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

We have to call some method instead of invoking `throw new IOException()` because otherwise we will have an error with `Unreachable statement`.

Then we can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to recompile the Other class. It will now be HotSwapped (a dialog will ask if you really want to do this).

Then press continue and the exception will be thrown.

The code can then be reverted back to normal state.

The good thing about this is that the recompiled class will even be hot swapped "over the wire" to the remote machine.

The important thing is that the code that you recompile must be in another class. The same class where you have your breakpoint won't be reloaded correctly.

> As a work around, I can modify the code to throw the exception and redeploy. But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in the debugger without modifying source code.

You will modify the code but only at the time when you want to, in the debugger. You can then revert back the small change and recompile to hot swap back the old code.

I hope you get the idea (no pun intended).

I can add screenshots if you want to.

Comment: OK that might work.  In my experience HotSwapping works like 30% of the time, but this may be fine.  Thanks

Comment: @tieTYT Hope it works for you more than 30% of the time. I'm out of ideas now, this was the best I could come up with :-)